# Перекрасить Строки DataGrid MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Работаю с `MvvmLight`. Есть дата грид который заполняется при помощи вьюмодели :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выделить строки, помеченные красным другим цветом. Я пытаюсь это осуществить с помощью `LoadingRow` которое привязано к команде во вьюмодели. Разметка XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" MinWidth="200" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding CountPaper}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Money" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Money}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aq.Price" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding AqPr}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Класс вьюмодели

```
private SolidColorBrush hb = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure);
...
public ICommand RowColor {
    get {
        return new RelayCommand(() => ....);
    }
}
```

Что писать дальше не знаю, подозреваю что и на этом этапе не все правильно сделал. Подскажите как перекрасить строки, у которых только 1 ячейка не пустая?

Comment: Я бы сделал конвертер из строки в цвет и попробовал бы юзать его

Comment: @tym32167 к сожалению я не понимаю что вы имеете в виду

Comment: По идеи `MVVM`: `SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure);` - такой шляпы на вью модели быть не должно. Вьюха и только вьюха отвечает за отображение.

Comment: @AGS17 переместить в code-bechind ?

Comment: @Сергей не вижу смысла. Просто сделайте `ControlTemplate` и конвертите в требуемый вам цвет.

Comment: @AGS17 это элемент разметки, насколько знаю. т.е. достаточно только модифицировать `xaml` ?

Comment: @Сергей может потребуется писать конвертер

Comment: @AGS17 что представляет Конвертер ?

Comment: @Сергей [пример](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/IValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь конвертером. Для этого нужно создать класс, который преобразует элемент строки в кисть и реализует [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class RowToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(Brush))
        {
            return null;
        }

        // RowType - тип элемента строки
        var r = value as RowType;
        if (r == null || r.Date != null ...)
        {
            return Brushes.White;
        }

        return Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

В разметке DataGrid добавляем:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:RowToBrushConverter x:Key="RowToBrushConverter"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RowToBrushConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```